# Extract pair numbers from array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Good evening, folks.

I'm currently experiencing difficulties with extracting pair numbers from an array. I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int *paire(int *d, int length) {
    int counter = 0;
    int position = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<length; i++) {
        if (d[i] % 2 ==0)
            counter++;
    }

    int *k = new int[counter];
    for (int i=0; i<length; i++) {
        if (d[i] % 2 ==0) {
            k[position] = d[i];
            position++;
        }
    }
    return k;
}

int main() {
    int b[8] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
    int *array1 = paire(b,8);
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) { // how can I point here to the counter in paire() ?
        cout<<array1[i];
    }
   delete[] array1;
    return 0;
}
```

So I think I've got it right with initializing the new array in function `paire`, but I'm having difficulties to iterate through the array.

P.S. I'm first year in university, so I would really be thankful if you can keep the same simplicity in the answers. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you used `std::vector<int>` rather than that bare pointer, then all your issues - including a memory leak - will go away.

Comment: I would love to expand my knowledge, but I'm afraid that I have to stick with new[] and static arrays until my exams pass :/ 

(I'm just trying to comprehend everything in my revisions for the exam)

Comment: dont be afraid. using `std::vector` is easier not harder than raw pointers

Comment: I'm afraid because if I use std::vector in my exam sheet, that might not pass as the wanted answer and for now I'm struggling to pass 2nd year. 

Thanks for the suggestions, much appreciated !

Comment: "I'm having difficulties" is not a problem description. What difficulties? What is not happening that you need to happen, or is happening wrongly?

Comment: Read [mcve] and [ask]

Comment: If you must `new []` then please also `delete [] array1;`

Comment: Why not create  a ```class``` and use RAII?

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you need to return 2 separate values: the number of even numbers in the array b, and the address of the newly allocated memory that is storing exclusively those even numbers.

Since you can not return multiple variables, one solution that does minimal modification to your code would be as follows.

```
int *paire(int *d, int length, int& counter) {
    counter = 0;

    // rest of your function remains unchanged
    // ...
}

int main() {
    int b[8] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
    int evenNumbers;
    int *array1 = paire(b,8, evenNumbers);
    for (int i=0; i<evenNumbers; i++) {
        cout<<array1[i];
    }
    delete [] array1;
    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, you can return the value in `counter` and send the reference to the `int*` variable as an argument to `paire` function. Or, you can declare `paire` to have return type `void` and use references to *pass back* both the values.

Answer (score 0):

You can further simplify your function by allocating to that of the `length` and returning the `counter` by an output parameter.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int *paire(int *d, int length, int &counter) {
    counter = 0;
    int *k = new int[length]; // allocate for the maximum memory
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        if (d[i] % 2 == 0) {
            k[counter++] = d[i];
        }
    }
    return k;
}

int main() {
    int b[8] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
    int counter = 0;
    int *array1 = paire(b,8, counter);
    for (int i=0; i<counter; i++) { // how can I point here to the counter in paire() ?
        cout<<array1[i] << " ";
    }
    delete [] array1;
    return 0;
}
```

But please note that as others have already pointed out this method is quite error prone in the sense that it leaves the responsibility to the client to delete the internal memory used by `paire` function.